# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous when iterating an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm implementing an array iteration in python like the following .

```
def incrementalAdd(self,p,eps,Minpts):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        print("\nADDING point "+str(self.num))
        self.visited = []
        self.newCores = []
        UpdSeedIns = []
        foundClusters = []
        NeighbourPoints = self.regionQuery(p,eps)
        if len(NeighbourPoints) >= int(Minpts):
            self.newCores.append(p) 
        self.visited.append(p)
        for pt in NeighbourPoints:
          print('pt:')
          print(pt)
          print('self.visited:')
          print(self.visited)
          i=0  
          for i in range(len(pt)):
            if pt[i] not in self.visited:
```

If I print the values of pt and self.visited, I get the following values:

```
pt:
[766.13 389.14]
self.visited:
[array([766.13, 389.14])]
```

however it shows me an error:

```
valueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution to solve this.

Comment: Please add more details *(elements)* about self.visited and `pt` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.visited:
[array([766.13, 389.14])]
```

This mean you have list holding single array, thus the error, for example

```
import numpy as np
x = 389.14
visited = [np.array([766.13, 389.14])]
print(x in visited) # ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous....
```

you need to use flat structure rather than nested as visited, if it always has exactly one element which is 1D array you might just access it

```
import numpy as np
x = 389.14
visited = [np.array([766.13, 389.14])]
print(x in visited[0]) # True
```